# Flex - How to edit a xml file on the server

Tags: xml, apache-flex

I was wondering if it was possible to edit an xml on the server side from a web based flex application. 
When you use XML files in a Flex application and then compile it to upload it in the server, Flex Buidler generates a swf file with the xml data embedded. How should I do to have access to those XML files??

Thanks for your answers.

Regards.
BS_C3

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you want to be able to read some XML files which are deployed on some server? Do you want to edit the content and save it back?

Comment: You mean like through a web service?

Comment: Hi!
I'd like to edit the content of the XML file and save it. 
The server is a J2EE server and I could use a java function to read, edit and save the content. However, I was wondering if it is possible to do that directly through the application without going through a java service call.
Regards =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load the content but you cannot save it back directly from Flash without calling some server side method. You should pass the new content (or delta) as a parameter to this method on the server side.

Comment: Hi!
Thaks for your answer. That's what I was looking for =)
Regards.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question you're using a XML mxml tag that embeds the XML. Try to use a URLLoader instead. Maybe like this:

```
var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        var myXml:XML;

        function init():void
        {
            xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlLoaded);
            xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest('teste.xml'));
        }
        function xmlLoaded(e:Event):void
        {
            myXml = new XML(e.target.data);
        }
```

Comment: Hi!
Thanks for your answer, but this enables me to load the content. What I'd like to do is to edit and save the content back into the XML file. Do you know how to do that without using a service? 

Also, what is the eventlistener for? Couldn't you just do 
function init():void
{
    xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest('test.xml'));
}
??
Regards